# Controlling how often an Entity Framework ObjectContext is created

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, edmx

I have a rather large SQL backed ASP.NET project that uses Entity Framework to interact with the database.

My question is, should I create an instance of the ObjectContext defined by the edmx/designer files in each class/method -or- wrap it around a static class that would instantiate onload and basically handle all requests through one instance.

I will have multiple users using the ObjectContext to read and update the DB, concurrency and thread safety are my utmost concerns.

**EDIT:**
This code would ultimately run in IIS and be susceptible to recycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you just need single context for every request. Only special scenarios can need more contexts per single request but [never share context among requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392).

Answer (score 0):

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data
>   objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded
>   scenarios.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx

Therefore the best approach is to use an ObjectContext per HTTP request. Make a `RepositoryBase` class that every repository extends from and in the `RepositoryBase` define common CRUD operations (**preferably generic**) and make a new instance of only if it's `null` on requesting for it.